# View animations are suddenly gone after using layer animations

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, calayer, cabasicanimation, catransaction

I'm using CABasicAnimation and CATransaction to animate some layers in my custom UIView.

However, when after that returning to the rest of my app using a navigation controller's back button, the navigation controller does not animate anymore. Not even when then going to any other view.

I am using an iPad with iOS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to workaround this by calling

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

in my viewDidDissapear and viewWillDisappear methods.

Really strange since I am never disabling view animations anywhere in my code.

Comment: Did you set your animation speed to zero anywhere? Are you using CATransactions?